# jQuery autoescaping Django templatetags

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to integrate jQuery with my Django project using .load calls. All's well when I hard-code stuff, but when I try something like `$("#one").on('click', function() {$(this).load("{% url 'path.to.myView' %}")});` it doesn't work, and the message I get from the console (I'm testing this with `runserver`) says:
`[16/Nov/2013 20:37:18] "GET /%7B% HTTP/1.1" 404 3178`
I looked it up, and `%7B%` is the html escaped equivalent of `{`, so it seems that the template tag is getting escaped, somehow. I tried wrapping this in `{% autoescape off %}`, but it didn't work.

All the other Django+jQuery-related stuff I've seen on SO suggest this kind of thing "just works", but I'm not having any luck.

Comment: well, show us your urls and views path

Answer (score 1):

Ok nevermind, I got it. The problem is that Django doesn't render template tags on flatpages, so the `{% url %}` stuff wasn't working. I also realized `{% url %}` doesn't work for views without `urlconf`s.